# Excel pivot table to show % which are 0

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Here's some pretend data:

```
    Apple       4
    Apple       0
    Apple       1
    Banana      4
    Carrot      0
    Apple       0
    Apple       2
```

I want to show the percent of each food that is exactly 0. So the ideal output:

```
   Apple        20%
   Banana       0%
   Carrot       100%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column to your data with the following formula filled down:

```
=--(B1=0)
```

Then set up your pivot table to calculate the average of the new column.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what that's doing, and it doesn't seem to work for me. Could you confirm what I should see there?

Comment: The formula returns '1' for records with a zero value in column B, and '0' for those that do not.  The pivot table (with rows grouped by Column A) should be set up with the average of this new column as the value. For example, the pivot table will display the average of {0,1,0,1,0} for 'Apple' -- 0.40.  You can change the formatting of the pivot table to display the averages as percentages.